# What is the largest chain of $(\{0,1\}^n,\leq)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Consider the partial order $(\{0,1\}^n,\leq)$, where $\{0,1\}^n$ is the set of all length-$n$-strings over $0$,$1$. For $x,y\in\{0,1\}^n$ we define $x\leq y$ if $x_i\leq y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. For example, $(1,0,0)\leq (1,0,1)$ but $(1,0,0)\not\leq (0,1,0)$.

What is the largest chain of $(\{0,1\}^n,\leq)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax}(https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Note that if $x < y$ then the number of $1$'s in $x$ is less than the number of $1$'s in $y$.  The maximum number of $1$'s is $n$.  So...

Comment: The is no largest chain, only maximal chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that the length of the longest chain in $(\{0,1\}^n,\leq)$ is $n+1$. An example of longest chain is
$$(0,0,0,\dots,0,0)\leq (1,0,0,\dots,0,0)\leq (1,1,0,\dots,0,0)\\
\leq (1,1,1,\dots,0,0)\leq \cdots \leq (1,1,1,\dots,1,0)\leq (1,1,1,\dots,1,1).$$
Note that if $X_1\leq X_2\leq \dots \leq X_m$ is a chain then 
$0\leq |X_1|< |X_2|< \dots < |X_m|\leq n$ where, for any $X\in\{0,1\}^n$, $|X|$ denotes the number of $1$s in $X$. Does this property imply that there are no chains of length greater than $n+1$?

Comment: This is not a hint

Comment: @theSharpShooter Any further doubt?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Mirsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirsky%27s_theorem).  Robert Z's example shows that the poset is of [height](http://planetmath.org/posetheightandwidth) at least $n+1$.  Since the poset can be written as a union of $n+1$ antichains $$A_i:=\big\{x\in \{0,1\}^n\,|\,x\text{ has }i\text{ ones}\big\}$$ for $i=0,1,2,\ldots,n$, the height of this poset must be exactly $n+1$.